# If statement in sq-lite

Tags: sqlite

I have a database of members who are in a club. One of the columns is if they are active or no (the column has data 'yes' or 'no'). I want to write a query where it only selects members who are active. How do I write a query for? I have come up with the following code, If it is wrong please correct it for me.

```
CASE Yes when Active then select * from StudentData
```

Note-
Active - name of column
StudentData - name of table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM StudentData WHERE Active = 'Yes' ORDER BY State
```

And I recommend [Codecademy's Learn SQL](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-sql) and the [w3schools SQL tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) to get a handle on the basics. We all started somewhere.

Comment: No problem. If you're satisfied with the answer, you can go ahead and mark it as accepted. And have fun learning SQL.

Comment: One more thing, I also have to order this based on state is it possible you could help me with that as well. I can't accept it for 4 more mins

Comment: OK, what is the column name? Is it `State`?

Comment: OK, done. And definitely take some time to learn SQL. It's a valuable skill for any programmer.